# alertview with textfield gets crashed in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uialertview

Am in need of using uialertview with textfield so as to pass the entered text to a webservice integration, while the application is being running the alertview with textfield is displayed and can enter the text in textfield, but while clicking the submit button, the respective class is crashed but the back button and entire application is working good.

Code which I used for the alertview with textfield,

```
{
            //alertview with textfield
           UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter your changes"
             message:nil
             delegate:self
             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
             otherButtonTitles:@"Submit Changes", nil];
             [message setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
             [message show];
}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

{
    if (buttonIndex == 1)

    {
       text = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];

        NSLog(@"passed value %@",text);

    }
}
```

Comment: whre exactly crashed log it i think text = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text]; this line get crashed .... what is text

Comment: @JitendraDeore, while running the application with the alertview   and textfield without adding the willdismisswithbuttonindex,clicking on the submit button shows the same crash, so the text = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text]; would't be the case i think

Comment: i checked you code by running it..it never crashesh....code is perfect. error is might be in your another code.

Comment: post more code to understand issue

Answer (score 0):

Where's that code placed? Without more context, these two guesses are shots in the dark, but they are common pitfalls.

My first guess is that this very object (which is the delegate of the alert view) is already dead when the dialog gets closed. And the delegate is assigned, so it will be called on a dead object, leading to crash.

Another possible reason is that your code is in a class method, i.e. `+(void)showMessage;`. Then you set the delegate to the class but not the object, which should trigger a crash as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may be declaring objects out of scope, causing a crash when you are trying to access an object that no longer exists. More code would be useful